# Try to get client's computername in Django

Tags: python, sockets, wmi

I want to get the client's computername and computer login user in my django project in the intranet. So I use wmi  with the ip to get that infomation. However some ip could not be connected by wmi, and come up with an error called "The RPC Server is unavailable". Then I try to use the computername to connect by wmi for testing, it worked. What causes this problem? I have used socket.getnamebyaddr also get the wrong computername.

'''

```
 import wmi
 ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
 try:
    conn = wmi.WMI(computer = ip,user = 'xx', password="xx")
    for each in conn.Win32_ComputerSystem():
        content = {
            'user':json.dumps(each.UserName),
            'comname':json.dumps(each.Name),
        }
        print(each.Name)
        print(each.UserName)
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

Use socket module instead of wmi.

```
import socket

hostname = socket.gethostname()
ip_address = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)

print(f"Hostname: {hostname}")
print(f"IP Address: {ip_address}")
```

More information can be found [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python-program-to-find-the-ip-address-of-the-client)

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have used the socket.gethostbyaddr(), but sometimes it could not get the right hostname. Maybe there is something wrong in the DNS?